# The volume between 2 planes and a octant

Tags: calculus, geometry, analytic-geometry

The problem that i tried to solve have this particular case:

Problem : In $R^3$, Let
$P_1$ be the plane
$x+y+z=l$, $l$ greater than $0$, and let $P_2$ be a generic plane with equation $a x+b y+c z=0$, with {a,b,c} not all with the same sign (otherwise, our problem would'n be well definied since the vector (a,b,c) would be in the first octant). Find the 2 volumes of the regions determined by the the 2 planes and the first octant.

The general case is a generalization of this problem to higher dimensions that i come up and can't solve it:
In $R^n$, Let
$P_1$ be the plane
$x_1+x_2+ ... + x_n=l$, $l$ greater than $0$, and let $P_2$ be a generic plane with equation $a_1 x_1+a_2 x_2+...+a_nx_n=0$. Supposing that this problem is well defined, Find the 2 volumes of the regions determined by the the 2 planes and the first "octant" (i.e., the points $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ with $x_i>0, i = 1,...,n$).

Comment: What is your work on the subject ?

Comment: I come up with this problems when i tried the following problem: let $n = n_1 +n_2+...+n_k$ be a partition of n in k naturals, and lets define a function G associate with each partion by the formula $G = g_1 n_1+g_2 n_2+...g_k n_k$, where these g's are constant real numbers. What is the probability that, supposing that each partition have the same probabilty of happening, we got G greater then 0. The problem proposed here may give a estimative to this probability for n. note: you might be asking me another thing, so sorry if i did'n give the answer that you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the two planes with equations:

$$\begin{cases}(P_1): \ &x+y+z&=&L\\(P_2): \ &ax+by&=&z \end{cases}$$

(with an unimportant difference of notation with you for the second equation),

[image]

*The intersection of plane $(P_1)$ with the first octant is an equilateral triangle (yellowish).  Here we have taken $L=3$. Plane $(P_2)$ (dark green) has here equation $z=-2x+3y.$*

we obtain intersection points with:

$$\begin{cases}A(0,L/(b+1),Lb/(b+1))\\B(-bL/(a-b),aL/(a-b),0)\\C(0,L,0)\end{cases}$$

The volume of tetrahedron $OABC$ will be obtained classically as

$$\dfrac16 \det[\vec{OA},\vec{OB},\vec{OC}]=\dfrac{L^3b^2}{6(b - a)(b + 1)}$$

The other volume can be easily computed by difference.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed comment. Integer partitions are an unextinguishable source of questions...

Comment: I deleted my first coment when i was editing because of a mistake that (i perceived it when i took n large, and because i know that the average value must aproach $n *M$, it can't grow quadractly). Anyway, thanks for your attention, and have a nice day.

Comment: ... a nice evening in my case (10:00 pm C.E.T.)...

Comment: Well, from where i from, a nice day can be applied for all day long, with exception, of course, of the night. In any case, good day, good evening and good night.

Comment: Btw, can you say where you are from ?

Comment: I from south in Brazil.

Comment: I have been visiting some years ago the university of Porto Alegre. I come back to partitions: I am precisely working on them for another question dealing with $(0-1)$ matrices ; if you want to see the article referenced in my answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3925045

Comment: Interesting. You might have visited my city (i from Florianopolis, which is just a 460 km from Porto Alegre). I not a professional mathematician, i just a student, and mathematics is a more like a hobby, even though i actually study in deep a few advanced topics like abstract algebra, topology and differential geometry, In particular, i really love read a few classical works in mathematics history, like the works of Poincaré and Galois (probably, the hardest reading that i ever had, but also the most satisfying).

Comment: To finish, I first come with this problem when i was studying probability, and it is more a curiosity than anything. This is it .Also, thanks for the links.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. The philosophical works of Poincaré are easy to read ; his mathematical works much less in particular because of notations.

Comment: What i found harder is not the notation itself, but a few results that he do reference in others works and that is not obvious for a modern reader. This is the case of his works in topology.

Comment: Yes sometimes, his writings look allusive. It is said that he used to write his papers almost straightforwardly, with hardly any erasure...

Comment: Interesting. I found curious as how a few works of him, compared with the works of others author from the same century, like Riemann, for example, were problematic to read. You see, i like to take notes when i read these historical works, taking me way longer this way, since i like to make interpretations and a few parallels between the historical work and the modern theory (for example, it took me a month and 20 writen pages to finish the work of Galois about solvabllity of polynomials equations), but in the case of his work in topology, i did'n finish it: after 2 weeks, i just gave up of it.

Comment: And, when you know that the published works of Galois have been re-written by Liouville (without Liouville, Galois would have been forgotten...)...